# jquery nextAll with until

Tags: jquery

Jquery `nextAll` is used to select all elements after the specified element. Here I am trying to customize `nextAll`.

I want to apply `nextAll` for all articles that are between after this div and before the another div.

```
-<div></div>
-<article>
-<article>

-<div></div>
-<article></article>
-<article></article>

-<div></div>
-<article></article>
-<article></article>
```

But here following code, affects all article element. Here, I tried `nextUntill` also, but found it is used to break within same kind of elements.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.fee_tm', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      $(this).parents('div').nextAll('article').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else{
      $(this).parents('div').nextAll('article').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

```css
div{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
article{
  display:none;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type='checkbox' class='fee_tm' />JAN
    </div>
    <article>
      one
    </article>
    <article>
      Two
    </article>
    <div>
      <input type='checkbox' class='fee_tm' />FEB
    </div>
    <article>
      one
    </article>
    <article>
      Two
    </article>
    <div>
      <input type='checkbox' class='fee_tm' />MAR
    </div>
    <article>
      one
    </article>
    <article>
      Two
    </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean with 'it breaks'? what happens exactly when you use `nextUntil`? Looks like that's what you need..

Comment: Use this **$(this).parents('div').nextUntil('div')** instead of **$(this).parents('div').nextAll('article')**

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra, Oh I had used `nextUntill` in wrong way. it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem :

1. You want to hide / show all available `<article>` after checkbox
2. You want to apply it in same HTML structure
3. Currently its showing all `<article>` which is next to clicked one.

Please check below code:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.fee_tm', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).parents('div').nextUntil('div').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parents('div').nextUntil('div').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

```css
div {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

article {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <input type='checkbox' class='fee_tm' />JAN
</div>
<article>
    one
</article>
<article>
    Two
</article>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' class='fee_tm' />FEB
</div>
<article>
    one
</article>
<article>
    Two
</article>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' class='fee_tm' />MAR
</div>
<article>
    one
</article>
<article>
    Two
</article>
<div>
    <!--top last checkbox click stop-->
</div>
```

**Note :** you need to apply one blank `<div>` at the end of last `<article>` to prevent hide/show for rest of the code.